# Arithmetic property of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f, g :X \to \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions on $X$. Are the functions $f+g$, $f \cdot g$ continuous?

Comment: Yes! The prove would be similar to the case $f,g:R->R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. The map $f+g$ can be written as a composition
$$X\xrightarrow{(f,g)}\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\xrightarrow{+}\Bbb R$$
The first map is continuous by the universal property of the product, and the second one is continuous because ... well, one can show that it is.

We also have continuity of $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$. That one gives the continuity of $f\cdot g$

Comment: I did know this proof but it seems strange because it doesn't depend on the topology of X. X can be any pathological space.

Comment: One could generalize further and replace $\Bbb R$ by any topological group, i.e. a group $G$ such that $+:G×G\to G$ and inverse map $-:G\to G$ are continuous, for example the unit circle $S^1$ with complex multiplication as $+$.

Comment: @RenatoTargino: Note that $+$ and $()\cdot()$, as well as $-()$ and $()^ {-1}$ make $\Bbb R$ into a topological field

Answer (score 0):

Yes: You can show that using the sequence criterium and the sum and product rules for limits.